# Do AJAX calls make DOM heavier in size?

Tags: html, ajax, dom

I have a 3 column structure for my site.

Links are shown at Left hand side layout.

User clicks a link, and I trigger an AJAX call to load middle column of layout. I load a complete template file in the middle column.

My question -
When user clicks another link, I make another AJAX call to load middle column.

After each sub sequent ajax call, does my DOM gets heavier in size, as I am loading different htmls in middle column, without refreshing whole page ?

Answer (score 0):

No. If you are replacing the data with new data then the old data is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes your DOM as you say is technically bigger and you are dynamically injecting HTML.  However, this should not be an issue, and certainly not on the client.  Size is only of concern if you are downloading the whole page.